# Boost.Asio streambuf: How to copy data in streambuf

Tags: c++, boost-asio, iostream, streambuf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy a streambuf's contents to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877652/copy-a-streambufs-contents-to-a-string)

Recently I am working around boost::asio::streambuf.
Because of my poor English I cannot express what I mean. So first, please look at the code below.

```
class bar {
public:
    int length() const
    {
         return sizeof buffer;
    }
    char* get()
    {
        return &buffer[0];
    }
private:
    char buffer[100];
};

template<typename Elem, typename Traits>
std::basic_istream<Elem, Traits>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<Elem, Traits> &is, bar& data)
{
    return is.read(data.get(), data.length());
}

boost::asio::streambuf buf;
buf.prepare(65535);
std::ostream os(&buf);
// some operations writing data to buf
std::istream is(&buf);
bar bdata
is >> bdata;    // #1
```

At #1, data will be read from `buf` and stored to `bdata`.

This causes that the data that is stored to `bdata` is deleted from `buf`.
I want to get data from streambuf, but don't want to change the streambuf's contents at all.

streambuf has a lot of data and the data I want are located in the beginning of streambuf.

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Really? I think the link above cannot be applied to this.

Comment: It can. Use `const char* header=boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(readbuffer.data());` to gain direct access to the data, but don't `consume`.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the second answer of "Copy a streambuf's contents to a string". And buffer_cast is what I want. Thank you!