# async_read_until finishing before delimiter read

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am having a problem using async_read_until.   I was originally using async_receive but the response from my server grew to be more than one packet, and I ran into a problem where async_receive would stop reading after the first packet was received.  I then looked into async_read_until and tried to read until a delimiter was reached.  This however seems to be a problem, whenever I use async_read_until, my streambuf object only seems to go until the first  whitespace.  Here is my code I am using:

```
bool request_handler::get_recommendation(std::string& content, std::string &returnJson)
{
    //Connect to recommendation engine
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(Settings::get_recommendation_ip(), Settings::get_recommendation_port(), boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);
    if(ec)
    {
        Log::error("Couldn't connect: " + ec.message());
        return false;
    }

    //Create post Message
    std::string request_information = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request_information += "Host: " + Settings::get_recommendation_ip() + "\r\n";
    request_information += "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_information += "Content-Type:text/plain\r\n";
    request_information += "Content-Length:" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(content.size()) + "\r\n";
    request_information += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    request_information += content;

    try
    {        
        boost::shared_ptr<bool> timer1_result(new bool(false));
        boost::shared_ptr<bool> timer2_result(new bool(false));
        boost::shared_ptr<bool> write_result(new bool(false));
        boost::shared_ptr<bool> read_result(new bool(false));

//        boost::array<char,8192> buf;
        boost::asio::streambuf buf;
//        buf.assign(0);

        boost::asio::deadline_timer dt(io_service);
        //Create write timer
        dt.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(Settings::get_write_timeout()));
        dt.async_wait(boost::bind(&request_handler::set_result, this, timer1_result, _1));
        //Call async write
        boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(request_information, request_information.size()), boost::bind(&request_handler::set_result, this, write_result, _1));
        io_service.reset();

        //Run until either the timer finishes or the write completes
        while(io_service.run_one())
        {
            //Write completes
            if(*write_result)
            {
                //Stop the timer
                dt.cancel();
                break;
            }
            //Timer completes
            else if(*timer1_result)
            {
                //Stop the write
                socket.cancel();
                return false;
            }
        }

        boost::asio::deadline_timer dt2(io_service);
        //Create read timer
        dt2.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(Settings::get_read_timeout()));
        dt2.async_wait(boost::bind(&request_handler::set_result, this, timer2_result, _1));
        //Call async_receive
//        socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf), boost::bind(&request_handler::set_result, this, read_result, _1));
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, buf, "]", boost::bind(&request_handler::set_result, this, read_result, _1));

        io_service.reset();
        //Run until either the timer finishes or the receive completes
        while(io_service.run_one())
        {
            //Receive completes
            if(*read_result)
            {
                //Stop timer
//                dt2.cancel();
//                break;
            }
            else if(*timer2_result)
            {
                //Stop the write
                socket.cancel();
                break;
            }
        }

        //Put result in return string
//        returnJson = buf.data();
        std::istream is(&buf);
        is >> returnJson;
        std::cout << "***" << returnJson << std::endl;
        return true;
    }catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        return false;
    }

}

void request_handler::set_result(boost::shared_ptr<bool> a, boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
    *a = true;   
}
```

I thought the problem might have been that I need more calls to read_until and the whole packet wasn't being read in at once, but I am unable to get any more data than "HTTP/1.1" of my response from streambuf I read into.  Any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: You read handler seems to be missing the `bytes_transferred` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
    is >> returnJson;
```

only reads through whitespace.  See the specification of [std::basic_string::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).  To get the entire streambuf contents, try [Copy a streambuf's contents to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877652/copy-a-streambufs-contents-to-a-string).

Comment: This seems to be the problem, thank you, I figured it was a problem like that.