# Convert std::ostream to std::string

Tags: c++, std

Legacy code I maintain collects text into an `std::ostream`.  I'd like to convert this to a `std::string`.

I've found examples of converting `std::sstringstream`, `std::ostringstream` etc to `std::string` but not explicitly `std::ostream` to `std::string`.

How can I do that?  (Ancient C++ 98 only, no boost please)

Comment: You can't "collect" anything in a [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), it's a base-class whose reference one passes around, and the reference somewhere must be referencing an actual instantiable output stream. So follow the call-chain to see what your `std::ostream` reference actually references, and if it's a `std::ostringstream` then you can easily extract the data from it. If it's something else then you're out of luck and need to use something else to get the output (adding a parallel writing to an *actual* `std::ostringstream` perhaps?).

Comment: Thanks!  That explains a lot of things.

Comment: I just can't believe nobody has a solution to this issue: how does one copy the contents from a std::basic_ostream into a std::string? The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473325/no-member-named-str-in-stdbasic-ostreamchar-with-gcc-and-clang-but-no-p) explains the underlying issue I'm having: gcc doesn't provide a `str()` function as part of stringstream while clang and msvc have it. So what do gcc users do to get the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If you have a a `stringstream` or a `ostreamstring`, object or reference, just use the `ostringstream::str()` method that does exactly what you want: extract a `string`. But you know that and you apparently have a `ostream` object, not a `stringstream` nor a `ostreamstring`.
- If your ostream reference is actually a `ostringstream` or a `stringstream`, use `ostream::rdbuf` to get a `streambuf`, then use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878100/3336423) to see how to extract a `string`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string toString( std::ostream& str )
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << str.rdbuf();
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {

    std::stringstream str;
    str << "Hello";

    std::string converted = toString( str );

    std::cout << converted;

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://cpp.sh/6z6c

- Finally, as commented by M.M, if your `ostream` is a `ofstream` or an `iostream`, most likely it clears its buffer so you may not be able to extract the full content as proposed above.

Comment: I don't think this works; the post you link to refers to an input stream's `rdbuf`.

Comment: @M.M: Just tested that (see live demo added to my post), it works when `ostream` is actually a `stringstream`, so I d'ont see why it would not work with others (like `ofstream`).

Comment: stringstreams always hold the content in memory, whereas ofstreams don't, I'd expect they clear their buffer once written the current line or whatever

Comment: @M.M: You are probably right, I commented my post to mention that. Maybe the answer won't work when `ostream` is not actually a `ostringstream`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 std::ostringstream stream;
 stream << "Some Text";
 std::string str =  stream.str();
```

Comment: By the way, OP says `I've found examples of converting std::ostringstream to std::string`, so he knows that...