# no member named 'str' in 'std::basic_ostream<char>' with gcc and clang, but no problem with msvc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, std

This code snippet (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hKDMxm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto s = (ostringstream{} << "string").str();
    cout << s;
    return 0; 
}
```

compiles and runs as expected with msvc, but fails to compile with clang 9.0.0 and gcc 9.2 giving this error message:`no member named 'str' in 'std::basic_ostream<char>'`. Looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str there is clearly `str()` member of `ostringstream`. Why clang and gcc are failing to compile this code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> there is clearly `str()` member of `ostringstream`

Yes, but according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) this overload of `<<` should return a reference to `basic_ostream<...>` rather than `ostringstream`.

libstdc++ (GCC's standard library) does exactly this, while libc++ (Clang's standard library) and MSVC's standard library behave incorrectly here, technically.

However, it seems there is an open [defect report](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#1203) suggesting that the overload of `<<` that works with rvalue streams should return the exact stream type that was passed to it. If it gets accepted, your code will be valid.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it would be nice if a solution to the problem were presented, something better than `#if ... #else ...` in the code that wants to call `.str()`.

Comment: @taranaki The solution is to use `stringstream` in the classical way: create a (named) variable. I don't know a good oneliner alternative, but you could make a variadic function (that concatenates the argumenrs with a stream), or use libfmt.

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<` is member of `std::ostream`, and returns `std::ostream&` as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

MSVC obviously has own overload this operator for `std::ostringstream`, what is not in standard

Comment: When linking to documentation, consider linking to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) instead of cplusplus.com, due to it having multiple problems relating to the accuracy of the documentation.

Comment: This answer needs a bit of clean-up (for example there's nothing obvious about what's happening here) but it's the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and solved it with a wrapper class like this:

```
#include <sstream>
struct StreamHelper
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    template< typename T >
    StreamHelper& operator<<( const T& value )
    {
        stream << value; return *this;
    }
    std::string str() const
    {
        return stream.str();
    }
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return stream.str();
    }
};
```

Then you can do your one-liner:

```
auto s = (StreamHelper() << "string1," << "string2").str();
```

If the compiler can figure out that the target type is a string, you don't need the .str() at the end and can use the implicit cast operator.

```
std::string s = (StreamHelper() << "string1," << "string2");
```

Comment: It should be possible to move the string out of the stream, see overload (3) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution if your compiler has this 'bug' mentioned in other answer: Make a variable for the stringstream!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream ss;  // or: ostringstream
    ss << "string" << " or other stream data like from put_time()";
    string str = ss.str();
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```